# Move RDS Roles to Another Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I'm in the process of planning for the moving of our RDS Licensing Server to a new server.  I'm currently on Windows Server 2012 and moving to 2012R2.  The information I've found on how to do this is pretty clear, but now I need to confirm how to handle the other roles.

When I first set this up is was a Standard deployment with all roles on one server with the exception of the RDSH role which is currently on its own server and all is good with it.  I just need to build a new Licensing Server along with the other roles of:

- RD Connection Broker
- RD Web Access
- RD Gateway

I don't have anything custom as I mentioned before, it's a default Quick Setup/Standard deployment, so if I can just install the same roles and configure them on the new server rather than migrate anything that would be preferred method.

Looking to get confirmation or anything that might of changed over the years since it's been a while that I had this configured. Any and all input is appreciated it, thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I'll be "that guy". Why are you moving to Windows Server 2012 R2, which is out of mainstream support?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the server OS issue, but this is a quick fix solution for a RemoteApp that's running on RDS that needs to be off on-premise and onto our cloud infrastructure, so for this plan this is what I'll be proposing to my team leadership but the other plan will consist of new servers, etc. as the cost will go up due to needing new license CALs along with consultants for the RemoteApp we have that's a financial package with very custom configurations.